# Force .java to .class compilation

Tags: java, class, module, compilation, minecraft

I'm experiencing some problems with my understanding of the java compiler.

If you know Minecraft you may know that there are many mods to the game, which are pieces of modified classes that are injected into the original .jar replacing the old (original) .class, the problem is that if you want to use 2 different mods that replace the same .class, this would be kinda impossible, unless you blend in the code of both of them and do some edition.

Well, I got the 2 mods that uses the same .class and decompiled both of the classes (the decompilation were SUCCESSFUL), analyzed, modified and created a .java file that works for both mods at the same time. My problem now is that I have to recompile this .java into a .class file so I can inject into the minecraft .jar, but every time I try to compile it, I get a lot of errors, such as `class, interface, or enum expected` and `selection does not contain main type` those errors were expected, because the code mentions a lot of external classes and does not contain main type really.

I'd like to know if any of you know anyway to kinda translate the .java to a .class binary file ignoring all the errors I've got due to what was mentioned before or if you have any other suggestion about how can I do it.

PS: This code is not a full program, thats why I got those errors, it would work perfectly when inside the .jar, please don't answer that it's pointless compile this file alone.

Comment: So just add the original jar file (and required jar files) to class-path to compile it, and then use something like winrar to replace created class in the jar file.

Comment: Thanks to your quick reply, but how can i add the jar to the class-path with javac?

Comment: @Kasama `javac -classpath jarfile1.jar:jarfile2.jar:jarfile3.jar:. ClassToCompile.java`. (Note: if this is on Windows, use `;` instead of `:`.)

Comment: I just tried everything that i could to compile it using the original jar in classpath, but still the same number and types of errors, i did `javac -cp minecraft.jar bg.java`. Can the class obfuscation that minecraft uses have something to do with it?

Comment: Also tried to include all the dependencies of minecraft.jar `javac -cp minecraft.jar:jinput.jar:lwjgl.jar:lwjgl_util.jar bg.java` (Note: I'm using Ubuntu, so it's ':') still getting errors

Comment: You can use JAD for that

Comment: This question could be improved by extracting the kernel of the problem - all the rest of the "dependencies" aren't on the compiler's classpath.  All the mincraft cruft can be removed.  Then, the first comment is also the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I'd like to know if any of you know anyway to kinda translate the .java to a .class binary file ignoring all the errors ...

It is not possible.  You can't "force" Java source code to compile if it has errors in it, and it sounds like that is what the problem is.

- It is not unusual for a Java decompiler to produce output that is not valid Java source code.
- If you make mistakes in your "analysis, modification, creation", your source code may not be valid ... especially if, as it seems, you are not experienced in Java programming.

---

If you post the **actual** source code snippets, and the **actual** compilation errors, we may be able to help.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

> I Have experience with java programming, it's just that I use Eclipse to compile stuff for me, so I never use javac by command line.

That is not the problem.  You'd run into the same issue if you tried to compile this code with Eclipse.

> If its not possible to recompile a class with error, can I edit a class within a .jar with some program that unpack decompile, show the code so I can edit and pack it all up again?

In theory, Yes.  In practice, you'd require a good understanding of bytecodes and the way that compiled code works to be able to pull this off.  In particular, if you get it wrong you could run into mysterious exceptions at class load time.

The fact that the input classes are obfuscated partly explains why the decompiler is having difficulty producing compilable code.

Comment: I Have experience with java programming, it's just that I use Eclipse to compile stuff for me, so I never use javac by command line.

If its not possible to recompile a class with error, can I edit a class within a .jar with some program that unpack decompile, show the code so I can edit and pack it all up again?

But i think I found a way to do it using the minecraft coder pack (mcp50), now I only need to know what .java file the obfuscated bg.class represents. Thanks anyway =)